# Solve system of inequalities modulo

Tags: number-theory, inequality, modular-arithmetic, nonlinear-optimization

Let $p \in \mathbb{N}$ be a composite number and let $x, y$ be vectors with elements from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of some fixed length (in my case it's 39). How to find such $k \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ that the value below is minimized?
$$
\max(f(x + ky)))
$$
Here, $\max$ is just maximum value of vector entries, while $f$ is the inclusion map from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm looking for practical solutions. In my case $k = 39$ and $p = 311^2 \cdot 313^2 \cdot 317^2 \cdot 331^2 \cdot 337^2 \cdot 347^2 \cdot 349^2 \cdot 353^2$. The brute force search over all values of $k$ is impossible.

Another version of the problem is as follows:

Given $0 \leq \nu < p$, find $k \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that
$$
\max(f(x + ky))) < \nu
$$

Is there any clever approach to any of the problems?

As an addendum, here's example on what exact function I want to minimize.
Let $p = 10$, $k = 3$. Here's example in Python:

```
p = 10
x = [4, 3, 8]
y = [1, 5, 0]
for v in range(p):
    print(max([(e+v*f) % 10 for e, f in zip(x, y)]))
```

Output:

```
9 6 9 5 7 9 4 4 7 7
```

So here, we know that the minimum is at $v = 6$ or $v = 7$.

Comment: @Macavity no, that's just my sloppiness in the code (sorry)

Comment: I guess in the equality $k=39$ instead of $k$ should be an other variable, because we want to find $k$.